# Java8: compiler error with generic version in lambda function

Tags: generics, lambda, java-8

Here I just create two simple class `Dad` and `Son`, Son is a subclass of Dad.

```
public class Dad {
 }

public class Son extends Dad {
}
```

Then I create a `Function` in other class to test

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<? extends Dad, String> fun = son -> son.toString();
        fun.apply(new Son());
}
```

But I came across a compiler error on `fun.apply(new Son())`, it says '*apply (captrue in Funtion cannot be appiled to (Son))*'. I am confused, the `fun` need a param of class which extends `Dad`, I give the subclass but is not right at all.

What's more! I try `new Dad()` as the param for the `fun`, but also got the error message '*apply (captrue in Funtion cannot be appiled to (Dad))*'

Finally, I don't know which param can be used when the `Function` with generic version.

Help~~~
Thanks! (⊙o⊙)

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do? If you know that the argument to your function `extends Dad` then why can't you just use `Function<Dad,String>` instead of `Function<? extends Dad, String>`?

Comment: Ok, at first I have a enum which element's name are SON1 and SON2, and here are tow classes Son1 and Son2, both of them extend Dad. Now from the outside I got the enum's name as param, like SON1 or SON2, I want to query the Son1 or Son2 from database by the enum's name, and return the attribute name of Son1 or nickName of Son2, both attribute is String, But I don't want to use the if block to judge the current enum, I only want to get the enum by name and query the database by enum, and get the attribute I want from the enum

Comment: So I create a attribute Function<? extends Dad, String> in enum, SON1(Son1 son1 -> son1.getName()). SON2(Son2 son2 -> son2.getNickName()). But when I apply it, I got the compiler error just like I show. Could you please help me? or I could only use the if block : (

Comment: Could you add the code with the enum? I'm not sure I'm picturing how your classes are structured from your description.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your patience, the enum code is just like this below: `public enum EnumTest {
    SON1((Son1 son1) -> son1.getName()),
    SON2((Son2 son2) -> son2.getNickName());

    private Function<? extends Dad, String> fun;

    EnumTest(Function<? extends Dad, String> fun) {
        this.fun = fun;
    }

    public Function<? extends Dad, String> getFun() {
        return fun;
    }
}`

Comment: It would be better to use `Base` and `Derived` instead of `Dad` and `Son`...  The analogy from our Chinese is confusing.

Comment: um....My English ability is so bad, I almost want to write in Chinese...so just be patient for a while, HaHa...( ⊙ o ⊙ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
class Daughter extends Dad {}

Function<Daughter, String> funcForDaughter = ...;
Function<? extends Dad, String> fun = funcForDaughter;  // ok

fun.apply(new Son());
```

If compiler let you do this, you could be passing a `Son` to a method that only accepts `Daughter`.  The same reason also prohibits you from calling `fun.apply(new Dad())`.

`Function<? extends Dad, String> fun` doesn't mean that `fun` works on any subtype of `Dad`.  It means that `fun` works on some specific subtype of `Dad` that's not known at this point.

By declaring `fun` this way, you make it unsafe to call `fun.apply` on anything but `null` and so the compiler won't let you do it.

Comment: Thanks : ), as what you said, I can't declaring the `Function` like this way `Function<? extends Dad, String> fun`, maybe I should think about other way for my code.

Comment: @Tony: you are trying to solve a problem which doesn’t exist, complicating matters with Generics. Just use `Function<Dad, String>`. A function which can accept instances of `Dad` is already capable of accepting instance of subclasses, including `Son`, if `Son` is a subclass of `Dad` (quite a weird thing). It’s not Generics but basic OOP that you can always pass an instance of a subclass of the required type.

Comment: @Holger: Thanks for your reply, it's true when I use `Function<Dad, String> fun`, it can accept the subclass of `Dad` as param, but I can't initialize the function with subclass, why I want to use the generics version because there are two subclass of `Dad`, Son1 and Son2, when come a instance of Son1, I want to get the value attribute 'name' of Son1, like `Son1::getName`, when come a instance of Son2, I want to get the value attribute 'nickName' of Son2, like `Son2::getNickName`,   (refer to my next reply)

Comment: @Holger: So I define a function like `Function<? extends Dad, String>`, one initialization pattern is `(Son1 son1)->son1.getName()`, another pattern is `(Son2 son2)->son2.getNickName()`, when I got a instance,  maybe is Son1's or Son2's, applying the funtion and got the compiler error...

Comment: A declaration like `Function<? extends Dad, String> x = (Son1 son1) -> son1.getName()` makes no sense. The function `(Son1 son1) -> son1.getName()` *requires* the input to be `Son1`, so declare it as `Function<Son1, String> `. In your question you wrote `Function<? extends Dad, String> fun = son -> son.toString();` which happens to work because `son` gets the inferred type `Dad` which has a `toString()` method, so you could also write `Function<Dad, String> fun = son -> son.toString();`. Adding `? extends ` to an input type of a function just makes the function unusable.

Comment: @Holger: Thanks for your reply, it's true that adding `? extends` to a input type of a function just makes no sence, What I want just to be impossible, in a words, thanks a lot. : )